# How to replace value in javascript or ecmascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

I need to replace All in s3data Emp_Id with the response data's values(expected output appended), ignore 0 and 1 in response they are not required.
S3data is json data
I can't use inbuilt function like Object.fromEntries because they are not working in apache nifi execute script. So I have to do this with foreach or with loop so that it can work in nifi.
I tried it but it didn't work.

```js
var response = {
    "status": "success",
    "data": [[123, 0], [124, 0], [446, 0], [617, 1], [620, 0], [470 ,1]]
};

var s3Data = {
    "Emp_Id": "All",
    "Emp_loc": 523,
    "Emp_dept": "Management",
    "Emp_sub_dept": "Finance",
    "Emp_sub_dept2": "Accountant"
};
var result={}
var dataName = s3Data[0].Emp_Id;
   response.data.forEach(function(elem, index) {
      if(dataName==='All'){
        result[0].Emp_Id=elem[0];
      }
      
    });

console.log(result);
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
[
  {
    Emp_Id: 123,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 124,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 446,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 617,
    Emp_loc: 523,
   Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 620,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 470,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  }
]
```

**EDITED:**
So here is a little update in the question I tried to add more data to s3Data with condition that if there is no All inEmp_Id then it will be pushed to result as it is or if it have All then it will be replaced by api response but not getting expected result,

```
var response = {
    "status": "success",
    "data": [[123, 0], [124, 0], [446, 0], [617, 1], [620, 0], [470 ,1]]
};

var s3Data = [
{
"Emp_Id": "All", 
"Emp_loc": 523, 
"Emp_dept": "Management",
"Emp_sub_dept": "Finance",
"Emp_sub_dept2": "Accountant"
},
{
"Emp_Id": "1230",
"Emp_loc": 522, 
"Emp_dept": "arts", 
"Emp_sub_dept": "Finance",
"Emp_sub_dept2": "Accountant"}
];

var IDs = response.data;
var result=[];

for(var j=0;j<s3Data.length;j++){
var getEmpId = s3Data[j].Emp_Id;
if(getEmpId==='All'){
for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
  var id = IDs[i][0];
  s3Data.Emp_Id = id;
  result.push(s3Data)
}
}else{
    result.push(s3Data);
}
}


console.log(result);
```

**Expected result for edited part**

```
[
  {
    Emp_Id: 123,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 124,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 446,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 617,
    Emp_loc: 523,
   Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 620,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 470,
    Emp_loc: 523,
    Emp_dept: 'Management',
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  },
  {
    Emp_Id: 1230,
    Emp_loc: 522, 
    Emp_dept: 'arts', 
    Emp_sub_dept: 'Finance',
    Emp_sub_dept2: 'Accountant'
  }
]
```

Comment: `s3Data[0]` doesn't make sense because `s3Data` is not an array

Comment: @Konrad Then how can I read this value? It is json data right?

Comment: You just need to do `s3Data.Emp_Id` to call the object property `Emp_id`. `[number]` is only used to call a specific index of an array

Comment: `It is json data right?` - wrong. JSON is only ever a string

Comment: @JaromandaX So you mean if 523 would be in "523" then it would be a valid json?

Comment: @dash no. this is JSON: `'{ "Emp_Id": "All", "Emp_loc": 523, "Emp_dept": "Management", "Emp_sub_dept": "Finance", "Emp_sub_dept2": "Accountant" }';`

Comment: @dash - no, JSON describes a data interchange format that is purely a string [as described here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Comment: How does the ID match the data? What is the expected output now you have data WITH an ID...

Comment: @mplungjan Actually I have data in these format and I only need to replace with apiResponse whenever there is All in Emp_Id. I thought it will be easy with if else to pass id thats why didn't included that but now I am stucking because not getting expected result..................Appending expected Result as well

Comment: @mplungjan expected result added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legacy JS answer

```js
var response = {
    "status": "success",
    "data": [[123, 0], [124, 0], [446, 0], [617, 1], [620, 0], [470 ,1]]
};
var IDs = response.data;

var s3Data = `[{ "Emp_Id": "All", "Emp_loc": 523, "Emp_dept": "Management", "Emp_sub_dept": "Finance", "Emp_sub_dept2": "Accountant" }, { "Emp_Id": "1230", "Emp_loc": 522, "Emp_dept": "arts", "Emp_sub_dept": "Finance", "Emp_sub_dept2": "Accountant"} ]`; // JSON string

var objects = JSON.parse(s3Data);
var resultArray = [];
var template = "";
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  var id = objects[i].Emp_Id; console.log("id",id)
  var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objects[i]));
  if (id !== "All") {
    resultArray.push(clone); // push a clone
  }  
  else if (!template) template = clone;
}  

// continue with the one without ID

for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
  var id = IDs[i][0];
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(template));  // copy
  if (obj.Emp_Id === "All") obj.Emp_Id = id;
  resultArray.push(obj)
}  

console.log(resultArray); // Object array
```

Comment: Can you please check my updated question block, tried adding more data to s3data but stucked again

Comment: See update. I hope that is what you meant

Comment: No, Emp_debt have arts in all of the output, it should be what it was originally in input only Emp_Id will be change, You are misunderstanding it Actually there will be data in hundreds not only these two so I can't do it like this I have to

Comment: @dash Oops, I forgot to test the ID again second time and to use the templage

Answer (score 0):

```js
var response = {
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    [123, 0],
    [124, 0],
    [446, 0],
    [617, 1],
    [620, 0],
    [470, 1]
  ]
};

var s3data = {
  "Emp_Id": "All",
  "Emp_loc": 523,
  "Emp_dept": "Management",
  "Emp_sub_dept": "Finance",
  "Emp_sub_dept2": "Accountant"
};
var result = []
response.data.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  const obj = Object.assign({
    Emp_Id: elem[0]
  }, s3data)
  result.push(
    obj
  );
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is correct but actually I have to use only json data, here result=[] is an array and this is giving error in nifi. We can only work with json objects in nifi ecmascript. I dont have knowledge of javascript much as I dont work in this techstack but its a short term requirement.

Comment: it is giving error on push if I change [] to {} on result

Comment: But your expected output is an array. You can't `push` into an object. Each item in an object has to have a key

Comment: can't use Object.assign it is giving error :( , in-built functions are not working in nifi execute script thats why I couldn't use map's Object.fromEntries. .... Any other way to assign Object value without using these inbuilt libraraies or functions?

Comment: `const obj = { ...s3data, Emp_Id: elem[0] }`

Comment: Can you please have a look on edited question block? I am stucking while trying with more data in s3Data.